# What is the best automation tool to update an object field if a date field is equal to current date?

Tags: trigger, workflow, process-builder, automation

Here's the scenario. I am to utilize the best automation tool to do the following:

> When the `Evaluation Date` field in `Meeting` object is equal to TODAY, tick `Evaluation Send` checkbox in `Meeting`

First, I tried it in Process Builder, however, this thing is only "triggered" if the object is updated. What I needed is to run the "action" when `Evaluation Date` equals to TODAY. So, basically, the tool has to monitor the date field of the object until it equal to TODAY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Workflow Rule and set `it criteria to created or created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria`.

Now create a new time trigger and run the flow based on `Evaluation Date`field.

To run the trigger on the same date as `Evaluation Date` field, do `0 hour after`

Also you should check [Considerations for Time-Dependent Actions and Time Triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en) and As per docs Salesforce does not automatically process the time-based worfklow but puts it to the Time-Based Workflow queue and processes it WITHIN an hour from the execution.

User can view the Time-Based Workflow by going to Setup and search for `Time-Based Workflow`.

And we can also do same process using process builder as well.

Comment: Thanks. How can I run the trigger to be exactly on the same date? The options are only `before` and `after` and `days` and `hours`.

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri do after 0 hours. So it will run on that day.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, you are right. It worked. By the way, I've found this [Considerations for Time-Dependent Actions and Time Triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en) and I've found out that Salesforce does not automatically process the time-based worfklow but puts it to the Time-Based Workflow queue and processes it WITHIN an hour from the execution.

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri yes If you have multiple flow execute in same time then it might delay. Also if help to solve your problem you can accept this answer.

Comment: Yes, I will. By the way, can I edit your answer to reflect the considerations things?

Comment: One more thing please, can you indicate that user can view the Time-Based Workflow by going to `Setup` and search for `Time-Based Workflow`? Please.

Comment: Process Builder can also do time based actions. It's not just workflow...

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with workflow. By creating a new workflow rule with evaluation when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria.